# How can I avoid styling the footer?

Tags: html, css

I have styles for the site but don't want them to apply to the footer. How can I achieve this?

HTML CSS Selector

```
@media(max-width: 500px){
#mobileview{
width:100%;
height:211px;
}

p {
    text-align: left;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size:70%;
}
br {
    display: none;
}
h1 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size:190%;

}
a {
    text-align: left;

        float:left;
}
a.animation {
    text-align: center;
        font-size:9px;
        float:center;

}
}
```

This is one of the code for my mobile view.

This is my code when calling footer

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="container2">
   XXX Content
  </div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

How do i exclude these style for footer ?  As it was messing with my footer

Comment: Show the code that assigns the `$footer` variable. Most probably it must be a *php include*. If so, check that section which has been included and assign those CSS variables there.

Comment: What is your question? we need more details?

Comment: Just add id attribute to the div you wanted for applying css style ..

Comment: @DavidJapan any idea how to do so ? i tried to do it , but it failed ( nothing changed )

Comment: I'm surprised that you're already using media queries, yet haven't even learned the basics of HTML/CSS. What you're searching for/experiencing is known as [Specificity](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot exclude styles for when elements match that reside in a specific context (blacklisting is not possible because [there is no parent selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector))

What you can go for, is a whitelisting approach, namely give your selectors context:

```css
main p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>I'm red</p>
</main>
<footer>
  <p>I'm not red</p>
</footer>
```

In this example, instead of doing

```
p { color: red; }
```

notice how I define the context that says *only `p` inside `main` shall be affected by this rule*.

```
main p { color: red; }
```